# SAS Addin for Microsoft Office not found in VBA Project references

Tags: excel, sas, office-addins

I have installed SAS Addin for Microsoft Office in my system. I want to create a VBA project to schedule a refresh on Excel. However in VBA Project / Tools / Reference I cannot find the SAS Addin library, so my code fails when loading the COM Object.

```
Dim SASAddin
Set SASAddin = excel.COMAddIns("SAS.ExcelAddIn")
Set AddinObj = SASAddin.Object
Set SASAddin = Nothing

'-----
' refresh the workbook
'-----
AddinObj.Refresh( workbook )
If CheckError("Addin.Refresh") = True Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Why SAS Addin reference is missing if I have installed in my system?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the reference manually. In VBA Project / Tools / Reference click on Browse and  try to find the library. That way should allow you to add the library.

Comment: Library is not appearing in the list, that is my problem! However is in Excel, but not in VBA Project

Comment: But in the reference dialog box, you can add manually references, browsing to them (it will ask for a *.olb, or *.tlb or *.dll file)